# Facebook Open Graph Markup not working

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I am using Facebook Open Graph Markup on this page:
http://www.muktbharat.com/index.php/article/display/hritik_leaves_movie/11093

But when I share this page on Facebook the Facebook is not able to fetch the image. But the og:image tag is present in website.

Please help. Why FB is not able to fetch any image from that website?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

From the Url Debgugger

og:image could not be downloaded or is too small

og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muktbharat.com%2Findex.php%2Farticle%2Fdisplay%2Fhritik_leaves_movie%2F11093

Your image specified is 180p x 240px. You should use a larger image.